# JOIN tables, only selecting newest row from second table, and conditional on second table data

Tags: sql, mysql

Say I have two tables. One has the main details, such as each row is a person and has their name. The second row contains every revision when someone changes "Hair color".

People

| People_index | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob |
| 2 | Susie |

Hair colors

| Hair_index | People_index | Color | Color-change time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Brown | 5:03 |
| 2 | 1 | Red | 5:07 |
| 3 | 1 | Green | 5:45 |
| 4 | 2 | Black | 5:02 |

Is there a way to LEFT JOIN the two tables so that for each row in People, I only get the newest row for each person in Hair Colors?

So, the result should be:

| People_index | Name | Color | Color-change time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob | Green | 5:45 |
| 2 | Susie | Black | 5:02 |

And then, for the other part of my app, I'd like similar SQL, but on top of selecting the newest row, it also only selects the rows that equal a certain value. For example, only select people where the most recent hair color is Green:

| People_index | Name | Color | Color-change time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob | Green | 5:45 |

Right now, I just select all people first, then looping through the rows, I check whether the newest hair color row is Green for each person and decide whether to add the person to the final array that way, but it seems that it could be a lot more efficient.

Comment: `Right now, I just select all people first, then looping through the rows`. SQL is a set-based language.  You don't loop through the rows.

Comment: If you will select those with Color:Green at the end why do you start with a `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: @Eric I mean that I select all rows, store them in a PHP array, then perform a new SELECT on each row from PHP.

Comment: @tinazmu I don't know. If there's a better way, please tell me.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` (as opposed to `INNER JOIN` or simply `JOIN`) is used when you wan all the rows from the LEFT table (the table that appears on the FROM clause before the other), regardless of whether there are matches on the RIGHT table. Since you don't want a row unless the latest matching row in the RIGHT table has Color:Green. So use INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
with PeopleAllHC as (
    select 
          P.People_index    
        , P.Name
        , HC.Color
        , HC.Color_change_time
        , Seq=row_number() over (partition by P.People_Index order by HC.Color_change_time desc)
    from 
        People P
        inner join
        HairColors HC
        on P.People_Index=HC.People_Index
)
select 
      People_index  
    , Name
    , Color
    , Color_change_time
from PeopleAllHC
where Seq=1
and Color='Green'
```

We get all hair colour changes in the CTE, number the changes from most-recent to oldest using the row_number() over function (this will assign 1 to the most recent) calling it PeopleAllHC. We then select the rows with Seq=1 to limit the output to the latest with the color we want.

(I have changed your table/column names to avoid using delimiters -backticks/brackets/double quotes- ; these are dbms dependent; you may need to adjust them accordingly)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try as soon as I get back to a computer!